# Why doesn't flex item fill the remaining space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align elements using flexbox

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6m7qnyp/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  flex: 15%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 150px;
}

.rightTop {
  flex: 85%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.rightBottom {
  flex: 85%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="rightTop">RIGHT TOP</div>
  <div class="rightBottom">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

As you you can see, the last element goes down under the .left div even though I set flex to 85%.

What I want is to make the right bottom element fill the remaining space under the right top element. It should look like this:

[image]

**I know that I can achieve this by wrapping right top and right bottom elements with a container, but I want to know if there is a way to do this with the current markup.** 
And also, can you please explain why the right bottom element goes down instead of filling the remaining space?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the right rows in a `flex` `column`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 15%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 150px;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rightTop {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}

.rightBottom {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="flex right">
    <div class="rightTop">RIGHT TOP</div>
    <div class="rightBottom">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah. I understand that it will work with a wrapper, but I don't understand why does it work like this now (why right bottom element goes down if there is enough space).

Comment: @alinaish because when elements wrap, it creates a new flex row. So the wrapped element starts a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I would just wrap the right side in it's own container called .right and go from there. Also I changed the heights of .rightTop and .rightBottom to match up.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <div class="rightTop">RIGHT TOP</div>
  <div class="rightBottom">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  flex: 15%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 150px;
}

.right {
  flex: 85%;
}

.rightTop {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.rightBottom {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  height: 130px;
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/bqyQWJ

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the top right top and right bottom div in a container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left {
  flex: 15%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
 width:15px;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.rightTop {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.rightBottom {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div>
   <div class="rightTop">RIGHT TOP</div>
  <div class="rightBottom">RIGHT BOTTOM
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it works, but my question is how to do it with the current markup and why right bottom element goes down

Comment: It is because you have set a flex of 85% on each div which is greater that 100% width of the parent container...

Comment: Not only is that the issue you concept of flex is somewhat strange, the elements will align horizontly   have as expected..try adjusting those values and see

Comment: I cannot see how 85% is greater than parent container. It's 85% of parent container width. No?

Comment: for guidance check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex